# Entity Framework Core Many-to-Many relationship with IdentityUser

Tags: c#, database, asp.net-core-2.1, entity-framework-core-2.1

I am looking a way to bind the default `IdentityUser` with a custom class but I am getting this error:

> Column names in each table must be unique. Column name 'AppUserId' in table 'HMTUser' is specified more than once.

`AppUser` class:

```
public class AppUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string FName { get; set; }
    public string LName { get; set; }

    public List<HMTUser> HMTUsers { get; set; }
}
```

HMT class:

```
public class HMT
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int HID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<HMTUser> HMTUsers { get; set; }
}
```

HUser class:

```
public class HMTUser
{
    public int AppUserID { get; set; }
    public AppUser AppUser { get; set; }

    public int HHID { get; set; }
    public HMT HMT { get; set; }
}
```

and have defined the OnModelCreating with

```
modelBuilder.Entity<HMTUser>()
            .HasKey(s=> new { s.HHID , s.AppUserID });
```

I am uncertain on `int` part as `AppUser` is derived from `IdentityUser` and `id` is `varchar`, will this be the case?

**UPDATE**

Changing the int to string did the job but ef core was asking for a PK in HMTUser entity so made a new one using

> [Key]

It works but it also create a new table name

> 'AppUser'

which is not used to store user data, user data is still saved in default

> 'AspNetUsers'

table.

Comment: Why don't you check that out by changing `int` to `string`

Comment: Ivan I tried but it creats a new table with name 'AppUser'

Comment: Changing the type of the column in one table cannot create another table. Does you context derive from `IdentityDbContext<AppUser>`? Anyway, changing the type of the `HMTUser.AppUserID` property to `string` in mandatory in order to match the PK type of the related `AppUser`. Any additional issues require separate question and [mcve].

Comment: @IvanStoev it works but creates a new table AppUser.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your code and I think one solution is to change the type of the `AppUserId` from `int` to `string`. With this change everything works fine. 
The code generated after migration:

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "HMTUsers",
            columns: table => new
            {
                AppUserId = table.Column<string>(nullable: false),
                HHID = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
                HMTHID = table.Column<int>(nullable: true)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_HMTUsers", x => new { x.HHID, x.AppUserId });
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_HMTUsers_AppUsers_AppUserId",
                    column: x => x.AppUserId,
                    principalTable: "AppUsers",
                    principalColumn: "Id",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_HMTUsers_HTMs_HMTHID",
                    column: x => x.HMTHID,
                    principalTable: "HTMs",
                    principalColumn: "HID",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
            });
```

Comment: Does it creates a new table as AppUser?

Comment: Create three tables AppUser, HMT and HMTUser. The only change is the type of `AppUserId` from `int` to `string`. Make a test of this code with the above change and you can see the code after migration.

Comment: it is creating AppUser table and save data in AspNetUsers table, so AppUser  is extra, also the HMTUser needed its own primary key.